# optional function inputs in PHP

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I notice that in some PHP built in functions such as str_replace there are optional input variables.  Can I have have optional input variables in my own functions?  If so, how?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 8):

The first way is to use default values for some arguments:

```
function doStuff($required, $optional = '', $optional2 = '') {
  ...
}
```

Now you just include a default value and then someone can do:

```
doStuff('foo');
doStuff('foo', 1);
doStuff('foo', 2, 3);
```

You need to choose an appropriate default value if the field isn't specified or to indicate that no value was set. Typical examples are `''`, `0`, `false`, `null` or `array()`.

Or you don't need to specify them at all with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function doStuff() {
  print_r(func_get_args());
}
```

`func_get_args()` can be used with explicit arguments (the first example) as well.

Comment: To expand on that, the assignments you give to the optional variables (where cletus writes the empty string '') are what you want their default values to be.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative you can do is this...

**EDIT**

somewhat useful function now..

```
function getLongestString() {

    $strings = func_get_args();

    $longestString = '';


    foreach($strings as $string) {
        if (strlen($longestString) < strlen($string)) {
            $longestString = (string) $string;
        } 
    }

    return $longestString;

}
```

Which you could then use like this

```
echo getLongestString('hello', 'awesome'); // awesome
```

Whilst this may not have been what exactly you were wanting, it is still good to know and solves the question of *optional function inputs*.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option that allows arbitrary ordering of arguments:

```
function my_function($arguments) {
  if($arguments['argument1']) {
    // do something
  }

  if($arguments['argument2'] == 'LOLCAT') {
    // do something else
  }
}

my_function(array('argument1' => 1, 'argument2' => 'LOLCAT'));
```